# CSS - UL Background Not Working

Tags: html, css, background-image, html-lists

For some reason when I try to set a `UL` background the background doesn't work. It works on my body background but it isn't working for the `UL`.

I know my image is named correctly. I have quadruple checked that. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Header</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="page-wrap">

            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>Main</p>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body 
{
    background-image: url('../Images/body-background.jpg');
}

#page-wrap
{
    width:1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#nav
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1040px; height: 185px;
    background-image: url('../Images/header-logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

From what it seems the `UL` itself isn't working with the `<a>` tag.  Without it the "Link1" shows up. With it though nothing shows up. Either way the background isn't displaying.

Thanks![image]

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Any screenshots?

Comment: I am testing in Mozilla, and I posted a screenie. Also I am writing this in Notepadd++ if that means anything.

Comment: I have tried this in IE 6,7,8, Chrome, and Firefox. It works in every case. Are you sure your image is in that folder with the name header-logo.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7MzE/2/

Looks like it's working to me.

Quintuple check that image for me.

Comment: I have... I even copied and pasted the entire directory location. Yet it's still not working.

Comment: You're in Mozilla right? Right-click the page, click view source, find your image in the source, left click that link, tell us what happens.

Comment: And you know, it looks like your main background is working so I doubt this is the issue but you might look and see if your css file is hooked up right or possibly try clearing your cache. Neither make sense to me in this case but I think its been demonstrated here that your code _should_ work, now it's time to figure out why it's not. You also might try another image, give one of the two I used in my fiddle a shot since we know they work.

Comment: Well it's not working with the external style sheet... When I put the css in the header internally it works perfectly? 

Why is this? Because my body background was working with the external stylesheet?

Comment: Open the source in Firefox and click on the css link to be sure its hooked up properly. If it is try Tools>Clear recent history...

Comment: Well I feel like an utter idiot. I recently transfered my project from visual studio to notepad++. I felt visual studio was a little overkill for something as simple as I am doing. When I copied it over I had 2 CSS files named the same exact thing. Except one was in the "CSS" folder while the other was in the main directory. Obviously I was pointing to the wrong CSS file. I thank you alot for your help. If it wasn't for you I would still be stumped.

Comment: Haha hey no problem, we've all been there. May this be the only bizarre bug you have to deal with on this project haha. Also good call on Notepad++, it's a pretty amazing piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Note that in my case, even placing a background image on a wrapper element was being hidden by the `ul` for some inexplicable reason.

**SOLUTION:**

```
ul{}
ul{background:url('image.jpg');}
```

Don't ask me why it works, but it does. And it works for ANY element you have this problem with, because it cropped up a few times for me.