# background image in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails 3.2.9 and I want to put a background image. my image is found in the folder: `public/images` and I put it also in the folder: `assets/images`.

```
ul { 
    height: 200px; 
    width: 350px; 
    border: solid 1px blue; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('/images/todo.png'); 
}
```

but there is no backgound image.
please help.

Comment: Where is this CSS placed?

Comment: assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss. I tried to change it to: ../images/todo.png, but it didn't work..

Comment: Try `../../images/todo.png`.

Comment: thank you but your suggestions doesn't work..

Comment: Can you give the us the full path for the CSS file and `todo.png` ?

Comment: background-image: url(todo.png);

Comment: todolist/app/assets/images/todo.png and todolist/app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss

Comment: Taras, thank you but it doesn't work..

Comment: `../images/todo.png` should work... It seems as though either the element you are trying to apply this style to isn't a `ul` or `todo.png` doesn't exist.

Comment: Alon, did you include your .scss in application.css? What is generated path in css?

Comment: @TarasNeporozhniy, I think it is included, because I tried to put background color and it works.

Comment: Alon , I am a bit curious : Are you trying to apply a background image to an unordered list ?

Comment: I have a 'ul' that contains some 'li'. I tried to add the background to the 'ul'.. (I hope you understand what I tried to say)..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to put:

```
background-position: center;
```

so my code is:

```
background: url(/assets/rsz_todo.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

and my image is found in `assets/images`

Comment: This was a kind of valuable discussion , you should accept your nice answer , Alon .

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check (before you edit your css) is to enter the path in the browser. This way your are sure what the path should be.

Your **app/assets/images** folder maps to:

```
http://domain/assets/
```

So if you have a app/assets/images/logo.png you should be able to retrieve that **in your browser** like:

```
http://domain/assets/logo.png
```

Then, in your CSS you should be able to refer to your logo.png like:

```
// app/stylesheets/application.css
body {
 background: url(/assets/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Also have a look at the Rails asset Pipeline:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: the image is found in: localhost:3000/assets/todo.png but I didn't understand the .logo that you wrote. please explain me because I don't have class="logo".

Comment: the .logo is just a simple wrapper, you can name it whatever you like.  I will adjust it for you body background.

Comment: check this, its a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754772/css-ul-background-not-working

Comment: thank you! the problem was: there is no: background-position: center;

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone finding this...[Rails provides helper methods for referencing an asset in your CSS or SASS file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

```
background-image: image-url("rails.png")
```

Turns into...

```
background-image: url(/assets/rails.png);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try just :

```
background: url(image.png)
```

The asset-pipeline is made up for simplicity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435141/background-image-in-rails#comment20097202_14435141 He said it doesn't work.

Comment: I've seen a couple variants , specifying the path before the source , but no one have tried pure `url(image.png)` . If the assets are OK (default) , it should be stated without paths to the image . If you try to use it like : `url("images/image.png")` , asset-pipeline is going to look for `app/assets/images/images/image.png`.

Answer (score -1):

If you put your image in assets/images then when calling that image you should use

```
background-image:url("/assets/image.png");
```

or you could try

```
 background:url("/assets/image.png");
```

And sometimes i have found using background rather than background image works better, but that is just personal experience

Comment: It doesn't work better, it's the same exact thing. `background` is just shorthand for applying multiple background properties such as `background-image` delimited by spaces.

Comment: and where is your image located?

Comment: dont know if it will make a difference but take it out of public and then use firebug or chromes console to see if the image is actually being rendered

Comment: is the image being rendered? ie can you see it in the console. try it with just background rather than background-image

Comment: the background doesn't work also. I'm really don't know why for all the people things work but not for me. This morning, I tried to search a solution but I didn't find a solution for me..

Comment: you havent said whether the image is actually being rendered, check in the console or as Rogier has suggested...