# How do I get a background picture into my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, background

CSS:

```
 body {
      margin: 0;
      background-image: url('../images/gplaypattern.png');
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #333333;
      background-color:#cccccc;

      /*background-color: #ffffff;*/
```

My picture file is in assets/images while the css is in assets/stylesheets

Comment: Try `url('images/gplaypattern.png');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url('/assets/gplaypattern.png');
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Yoshiji. However, I still can't see my background. I feel like I have tried every possible permutation.

Comment: Rogier's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435141/background-image-in-rails